# ERROR: permission denied for language c

Tags: c, postgresql

When creating a function like this with a non-super user I am getting the error below:

`ERROR: permission denied for language c
SQL state: 42501`

The function created is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_connect (text)
RETURNS text
AS '$libdir/dblink','dblink_connect'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

But if I wanted to give permission on language C to my non-super user, I am getting the error below:
`postgres=# grant usage on language c to caixa;
ERROR:  language "c" is not trusted`

That means, non-super user can't create function with language C? or is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you don't need grant `USAGE` privilege to `caixa` role explicitly, because it's granted to `PUBLIC` (all roles) already. The key here is `lanpltrusted` property from `pg_language` system catalog.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's right, according to [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-language.html):

> Only superusers can **create** functions in untrusted languages

Quick check:

```
SELECT lanpltrusted FROM pg_language WHERE lanname LIKE 'c';
 lanpltrusted 
--------------
 f
(1 row)
```

If you **really** want this, then you could modify `pg_language` system catalog ([`ALTER LANGUAGE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterlanguage.html) doesn't have such option):

```
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted = true WHERE lanname LIKE 'c';
```

Per user @Otheus below: the UPDATE statement must be done in the DB where the function will reside.

Comment: The update must be applied within the _database_ being used. I kept trying to apply it to the default database (_postgres_).

Comment: got this `ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_language`

Answer (score 19):

Instead of setting the language to trusted which is considered **bad**, and **dangerous**,
you should rather use roles to provide superuser privilege temporarily to the user during the time he manipulates the stored procedures:

as superuser:

```
create role dba with superuser noinherit;
grant dba to user;
```

then logged-in as user you can `set role dba`

And then you could create stored procedures in C while you temporarily have the role `dba`.

`reset role;` when you're finished to come back to normal rights.

[More info here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37336/cannot-create-function-in-plpython3u-permission-denied](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37336/10790)

Comment: `(no)inherit` works the other way. From the docs: *"These clauses determine whether a role "inherits" the privileges of **roles it is a member of**."* (emphasis mine)  That is, `user` is the one that needs `noinherit` in order to make `set role dba` necessary.  Setting `noinherit` on the `dba` role in this example does exactly nothing, since `dba` is not a member of any roles.

Answer (score 2):

In my case for uuid functions in RDS postgres 12.5.
All I had to do is:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp';
```

Comment: you save my life..

Answer (score 1):

Probably my answer will be useful for someone who is working with the relevant topic.

During DB movement from one project to another I was trying to re-create\recover a function `uuid_generate_v1` in the GCP Postres installation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uuid_generate_v1()
 RETURNS uuid
 LANGUAGE c
 PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp', $function$uuid_generate_v1$function$;
```

which failed with the same error as in the question `ERROR: language "c" is not trusted`.

I was not able to use any of the provided answers, because GCP doesn't provide superuser access to the Postgres.
But I found a workaround, which could be helpful for somebody.

Appeared that this function as-well as bunch of others (`uuid_generate_v1mc`, `uuid_generate_v3`, `uuid_generate_v4`, `uuid_generate_v5`, `uuid_nil`, `uuid_ns_dns`, `uuid_ns_oid`, `uuid_ns_url`, `uuid_ns_x500`), comes with `uuid-ossp` extension. So what I did I just create an extension which brought all necessary functions.

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```