# how to install postgres' tablefunc as non-poweruser

Tags: c, templates, function, postgresql, privileges

As part of our php data test framework, we start by dropping & creating a test database for the user running the test (let's call him 'foo').

Our template1 does not have a public schema. This is because we need the test db to have 'public' owned by 'foo' (and by default, even if 'foo' creates a db, Postgres will make 'public' owned by 'postgres', not 'foo')

Now, we need to install [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) on this test database.  Tablefunc includes C functions that cannot be installed as non-superuser (e.g. our user 'foo')

Can, and How can this be acheived ?  In any case, our php data tests MUST be run as non-superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily treat `c` language as [trusted language](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-language.html) and install tablefunc as non-superuser:

```
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted = true WHERE lanname LIKE 'c';
```

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014437/error-permission-denied-for-language-c/7014649#7014649) for more details

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Obviously not, however it's possible to run server in single-user mode with implicit superuser powers.

Comment: This worked for our purpose (sorry for the long delay since I posted)