# grant all in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I found that I cannot use `GRANT ALL` in [Cloud SQL PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#grantall)

But when I tried to execute a DDL script, I got error `ERROR:  permission denied for language c`.

I found out that in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014437/error-permission-denied-for-language-c), I need superuser access to pg_language.

How can I grant access to user on this table?

Answer (score 1):

Users you create using Cloud SQL should automatically have the  Cloudsqlsuperuser role which has the attributes (CREATEROLE, CREATEDB, and LOGIN), however, it  does not have SUPERUSER or REPLICATION [attributes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#default-users). Unfortunately you cannot update pg_language  table without  the [SUPERUSER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/role-attributes.html) attribute.

If you need full control of your database, You can create a Postgres instance on Compute Engine. Here it is the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/sql-server/creating-sql-server-instances).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  That is the whole point of them denying you superuser.  If you want total control of your database, don't use "Cloud SQL".  That is not what it is for.